# 3D scatterplots in sage

Tags: python, plot, sage

Is it possible to create 3D scatterplots in [sage](http://sagemath.org/)?

By scatterplot I mean graph like this:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolutely. If you've got a list of tuples that represent your points, something like:

```
point_list=[(0.,1.,2.), (2.,2.,3.)]
point3d(point_list)
```

that will plot the two points given in point_list, you can add axis labels with standard sage plotting options.

Answer (score 2):

You can, as indicated in the accepted answer. To produce exactly that graph (http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/scatter3d_demo.html) from Sage you can use matplotlib: copy the code of the example in a cell (I'm assuming you are using the notebook) and substitute the last line

```
plt.show()
```

with

```
plt.savefig("")
plt.close("all")
```